# Check that a vector is contained in a matrix in R

Tags: r, statistics, matrix

I can't believe this is taking me this long to figure out, and I still can't figure it out.

I need to keep a collection of vectors, and later check that a certain vector is in that collection. I tried lists combined with `%in%` but that doesn't appear to work properly.

My next idea was to create a matrix and `rbind` vectors to it, but now I don't know how to check if a vector is contained in a matrix. `%in` appears to compare sets and not exact rows. Same appears to apply to intersect.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: And what is the programming language please ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
wantVec <- c(3,1,2)
myList <- list(A = c(1:3), B = c(3,1,2), C = c(2,3,1))
sapply(myList, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), wantVec)
## or, is the vector in the set?
any(sapply(myList, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), wantVec))
```

We can do a similar thing with a matrix:

```
myMat <- matrix(unlist(myList), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
## As the vectors are now in the rows, we use apply over the rows
apply(myMat, 1, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), wantVec)
## or
any(apply(myMat, 1, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), wantVec))
```

Or by columns:

```
myMat2 <- matrix(unlist(myList), ncol = 3)
## As the vectors are now in the cols, we use apply over the cols
apply(myMat, 2, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), wantVec)
## or
any(apply(myMat, 2, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), wantVec))
```

If you need to do this a lot, write your own function

```
vecMatch <- function(x, want) {
    isTRUE(all.equal(x, want))
}
```

And then use it, e.g. on the list `myList`:

```
> sapply(myList, vecMatch, wantVec)
    A     B     C 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
> any(sapply(myList, vecMatch, wantVec))
[1] TRUE
```

Or even wrap the whole thing:

```
vecMatch <- function(x, want) {
    out <- sapply(x, function(x, want) isTRUE(all.equal(x, want)), want)
    any(out)
}

> vecMatch(myList, wantVec)
[1] TRUE
> vecMatch(myList, 5:3)
[1] FALSE
```

---

**EDIT:** Quick comment on why I used `isTRUE()` wrapped around the `all.equal()` calls. This is due to the fact that where the two arguments are **not** equal, `all.equal()` doesn't return a logical value (`FALSE`):

```
> all.equal(1:3, c(3,2,1))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 1"
```

`isTRUE()` is useful here because it returns `TRUE` iff it's argument is `TRUE`, whilst it returns `FALSE` if it is anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9


 v <- c(2, 5, 8)
```

check each column:

```
 c1 <- which(M[, 1] == v[1])
 c2 <- which(M[, 2] == v[2])
 c3 <- which(M[, 3] == v[3])
```

Here is a way to still use intersect() on more than 2 elements

```
> intersect(intersect(c1, c2), c3)

[1] 2
```